# Why can't I call to a var within a / /g;

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript to include textbox and a textarea. Button–calls a function to determine if the string in the textbox is found in the contents of the textarea. Naturally, message to the user if the string was found or not.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="textbox3" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>    
<input id="text3" value="" />
<button id="findTextButton" onclick="findText();">
    #2 Find text from textbox in textarea
</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function findText() {
    var txtThree = document.getElementById("textbox3").value; 
    var searchWord = document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML.value;
    var globalSearch = /[a-z]/g;
    var deliver = txtThree.match(globalSearch);
    if (searchWord === "") {
        alert("Please Enter Text");
    } else {
        alert(deliver);
    }

}
```

What I wanted to do was to call to the variable searchWord within the globalSearch function, but it's not letting me do that.

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense because `searchWord` is never used meaningfully or in context of `globalSearch`. If you're asking why *interpolation* doesn't work .. well, it's because Java doesn't support interpolation (but such is not even shown in the 'example' code).

Comment: I just realized this... as I was reading your response.  Any help would be great, I am definitely missing something..

Comment: @user2864740, It's JavaScript, not Java (but your point still stands)

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Doh, mistype :}

Comment: @S.franciotti Well, it depends on what the goal is. How *should* `searchWord` be used? Maybe just `txtThree.indexOf(searchWord) > -1`? You can of course use `txtThree.match(searchWord)` (the string will be converted to a regular expression, so you'll need to take that into account) which is the same as `txtThree.match(new RegExp(searchWord))`.

Comment: so I couldn't figure out how to make it work from your suggestions, here is what I did:
function findText() {
    var txtThree = document.getElementById("textbox3").value; 
    var searchWord = document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML.value;
    var deliver = txtThree.match(searchWord);
    if (searchWord === "") {
        alert("Please Enter Text");
    }else {
        alert(deliver);
    }
    
    }
@user2864740

Comment: I am still not sure what the *goal* is :} There is no globalSearch 'function'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `globalSearch` is a Regular Expression [literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29), it never changes, and will always find the same thing. The expression `/[a-z]/g` means find a single character between `a` and `z`. The `g` modifier makes it a [global search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global), meaning that it will keep searching and matching even after it finds the first match.

So, when you run `txtThree.match(globalSearch)`, [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return an array of single-character strings containing all of the letters in `txtThree`. For example if `txtThree` contained the string `'This is a test.'` it would return the array `[ "h", "i", "s", "i", "s", "a", "t", "e", "s", "t" ]`.

You can't use a RegExp literal to search for something that varies. You can however use the [RegExp constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Constructor) to generate a dynamic RegExp once you have your `searchWord`:

```
var rxSearch = new RegExp(searchWord);
var result = txtThree.match(rxSearch);
```

You can supply the `g` modifier as one of the flags in the second parameter to `RegExp`, but since you are just trying to determine *if* the string is in there are all, you don't need to keep searching once you find it once.

[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) either returns an array of matches (a single-element array in this case since we didn't use the `g` modifier) or `null` if a match was not found. Since [arrays are truthy and nulls are falsey](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) we can use `result` in an `if` statement to test whether anything was found:

```
if (result) {
  alert('Found somthing!');
} else {
  alert('It\'s not there.');
}
```

As [Buildersrejected points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322516/778975), RegEx is a little bit of overkill for this situation. Were I approaching this problem from scratch I probably would have used [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead:

```
if (txtThree.indexOf(searchWord) !== -1) {
  alert('Found somthing!');
} else {
  alert('It\'s not there.');
}
```

In this situation performance doesn't really matter, but if it did, using `indexOf` would be faster than useing [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search). `indexOf` actually takes a normal string as a parameter, `search` takes a regular expression, if a string is provided it is converted to a regular expression before being used.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I get what you are wanting....you have a textarea and a text input box. you want to grab the text from the input box and see if there is a match inside the textarea?

You shouldn't need a RegExp unless you intend to do more complicated things.
.search() can take RegExp or String.(In this case the value from "text3").
Also your checking if searchWord is empty TOO early. If Javascript runs into ONE error, the whole thing shuts down.

```
function findText() {
    var txtThree = document.getElementById("textbox3").value; 
    //var searchWord = document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML.value;
    //Take away the .innerHTML above
    var searchWord = document.getElementById("text3").value;
    //var globalSearch = /[a-z]/g;
    //You shouldn't need a RegExp.


    if (searchWord === "") {
        alert("Please Enter Text");
    } else {
        var deliver = txtThree.match(searchWord);
        alert(deliver);
    }
}
```

I tested this and it works fine for me. IF this is what you were expecting.

I will add that @UselessCode 's answer of using new RegExp(searchWord) is a good idea.

Comment: PERFECT!  I was very confused and this is so simple, I can't believe I didn't see it.

Comment: Agreed, RegEx shouldn't be used if it isn't needed. I would usually use `indexOf` instead of `search`. [`search` actually is converting your string into a RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Parameters) before it does its search.